# Firebase null pointer exception referencing child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am seeing an confusing null pointer exception for only ONE of the children of my Firebase Realtime Database reference.

```
Query query = db.getReference("comments/" + eventId).orderByKey();

query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
// This causes a null pointer exception.
Long date = dataSnapshot.child("date").getValue(Long.class);
// ...
}
// ...
}
```

I set a break-point and found that evaluating the following expression returns false.

```
dataSnapshot.child("date").exists();
```

The debugger displays this value for dataSnapshot:

```
DataSnapshot { key = c953b8fa-b569-4bc0-9302-3a9b34b22853, value = {0c2fd3e6-e9f1-43ce-a807-06b59e1b00bc={text=this comment is a comment., date=1515593659961, creatorId=gkbZMv2ThMh1xDwKyDP9oUtUIKi2, id=0c2fd3e6-e9f1-43ce-a807-06b59e1b00bc}} }
```

"date" is clearly present in the snapshot and all of the other children (e.g. "text", "creatorId", "id") are accessible. The only difference is that they are String values and "date" is a long.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

This means your code needs to handle the list by looping over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Long date = child.child("date").getValue(Long.class);
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you